# Поменять местами строки

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! Дано словосочетание из двух предложений. Нужно поменять их местами. Напишите пожалуйста алгоритм.

Comment: найти точку (или ?!) и по этому символу разделить строку на два предложения. Дальше просто сделать конкатенацию. Есть правда вариант, что первое предложение может заканчиваться на ... , но этот же символ может быть и в середине предоложения. Но 99% можно покрыть.

Comment: KoVadim подскажите алгоритм написания программы плиз

Comment: Возьмите учебник по java любой там это рассматривается...

Comment: И словосочетания бывают только из слов. Мне так то было бы стыдно спрашивать элементарные вещи.

Comment: ну два предложения

Comment: Как писать программу или алгоритм к данной конкретной задаче?

Comment: и то и другое)

Comment: -213 ! Как !?

Comment: -349)), легко)

Comment: как это возможно !?

Comment: У него 3 и может более вопроса, один вопрос за минусовали и администрация удалила, а так, кто нажал на тревогу, вроде минус 30 балов)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это задание, а не вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм я писал - если это два предложения, значит там должны быть соответствующие знаки, которые их разделяют. Это в большинстве случаев точка, знак вопроса и знак восклицания (экзотику не рассматриваем). Поэтому, находим такой символ и по нему разбиваем предложение. Дальше делаем обмен.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    private static String rotate(String s) {
        s = s.trim(); // удалим лишние пробелы в конце и начале
        int i = s.indexOf("."); / ищем точку
        // если точку не нашли либо точка - конец предложения, то пытаемся найти ! и ?
        if (i == -1 || i == s.length() - 1) i = s.indexOf("!");
        if (i == -1 || i == s.length() - 1) i = s.indexOf("?");
        // что то нашли, делаем разбивку
        if (i != -1 && i != s.length() - 1) {
            String s1 = s.substring(i+1); // первое предложение
            String s2 = s.substring(0, i); // второе
            return s1.trim() + " " + s2.trim(); // складываем их через пробел, предварительно вырезав лишнее
        }
        else
            return "Ничего не найдено!";
    }
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            // А это три тестовых случая
            System.out.println(rotate("One text. Second text."));
            System.out.println(rotate("One text? Second text."));
            System.out.println(rotate("One text! Second text."));

        }
}
```

Конечно, алгоритм прост и не справится с случаем "One text??? Second Text!!!!" правильно, но это уже отдельная задача.

Comment: спасибо большое братан! респект и уважуха тебе!

Comment: @KoVadim ну как не стыдно

Comment: За что мне должно быть стыдно?

Comment: @KoVadim, он имеет введу, тратить время свое, на то, чего он потом не научится))). Это я так понимаю студент 2-3-4 курса, а потом кем он пойдет работать если ему такая программа сложная)).

Comment: @Node_pro, программирование есть не только на IT-специальностях. Вполне вероятно, что это какой-нибудь менеджер.

Comment: Возможно, но насколько я знаю, то именно ява учится на специальностях связанно с программистами. =)

Comment: @Flammable, @Node_pro: Судя по уровню умений и стремлению переложить проблему на чужие плечи, даже не пытаясь подумать, -- таки да, менеджер.

Comment: я бы свое время на это не тратил, но расскажу вам историю. Как-то пришел друг сдавать что-то там, первый раз препода видит, там девочка, аспирант, возможно, посмотрела на него и поставила высший балл, он в шоке, типа "за что?", ее объяснение - "чем больше я таких дурачков на рынок труда выпущу, тем больше я как специалист буду ценится", так что... делайте выводы сами.

Comment: @Gorets: Талантам надо помогать, бездарности пробьются сами. (с)